# how to delete page from navigation stack - c# windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-runtime

I need to delete selective pages from the navigation stack (winRT- C#)

I checked:

[WinRT - How to ignore or delete page from navigation history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712562/winrt-how-to-ignore-or-delete-page-from-navigation-history)
and

[Pop pages off navigation stack in Windows 8 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047054/pop-pages-off-navigation-stack-in-windows-8-app)

but couldn't figure out how to manipulate the navigation stack.
Is it possible to manipulate this navigation stack?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278569/how-can-i-remove-pages-from-a-frames-history

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
```

Comment: Both RemoveAt and Count are not showing up for me. BackStack is type IEnumerable which doesn't have those properties.