# Changing to a different page in Snap View XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I've created a 1 page (MainPage.xaml.cs) dice app, and another seperate page for Snap View (Snapped.xaml.cs). Is there a way to straight away navigate to the Snapped.xaml from the MainPage.xaml whenever I go into Snap View? And then, once again, back to MainPage.xaml when I return to full view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First, place a `Frame` as the content of the current Window:

```
//this should happen when the app launches
var rootFrame = new Frame();
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
```

Then, have your pages inherit from a common page base to make it easier:

```
public partial MainPage : LayoutAwarePage
```

The default template for a GridApp includes a `LayoutAwarePage` class that you can start with.
Pass in a reference to the frame (or wrap it in your own [NavigationService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971023/page-navigation-through-viewmodel-using-mvvmlight-in-windows-8/10974150#10974150))

Then, handle view state changes to and detect when you are in Snapped / Fullscreen state, and navigate to the appropriate page. To detect the current view, use the `ApplicationView` class ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx)).