# How to implement onNavigatedToFrame in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, mvvm-light

I am working on a UWP project (Windows Phone 8.1) with C# and MVVM Light toolkit. I've tried Googling a lot, but couldn't find a solution for similar to onNavigatedTo event. I want to be able to call a method as soon as the user navigates to one of the views (pages). Can anyone help me out and give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:-

There is a new and simpler implementation here: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/navigationservice-in-mvvm-light-v5/
First we create the NavigationService and DialogService (for the page navigation params):

Details:-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26386815/5096993

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10974150/5096993
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx]1